# Why is a Slack bot sending files to users from me instead of the bot user?

Tags: slack-api

I have a database system that generates reports that my client wants sent to specific users in Slack. I've created a Slack bot and am writing code to test it out.

When I send a message using the bot and `chat.postMessage`, the message comes from the Slackbot. But when I send a file using `files.upload`, the file gets uploaded, but appears to come from my personal Slack channel as a direct message.

My preference is that it also come from the bot user, which it did when I originally wrote the bot a few months ago.

The only `curl` options I'm sending are `--form file=@slack_test_file.txt`, `--form channels=Uxxxxxxxx`, and `--header "Authorization: Bearer xxx...`. Neither the URL nor the `curl` options have any reference to my Slack ID (unless I'm sending the file to myself, but this happens when I send it to someone else too).

How do I get the file to appear to come from the bot user, or, if necessary, the Slackbot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong OAuth token. I was using the OAuth Access Token for the app, but should have been using the Bot User OAuth Access Token.